# Run a cleanup script when stopping a Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, signals, bash-trap

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
# ... there is more
ENTRYPOINT ["/root/startup.sh"]
CMD ["choose_random"]
```

So `startup.sh` is called with a default paramater if none is provided by the user.

My `startup.sh` is this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

# init database etc.
python3 /root/boot.py $1
# snmpd
/usr/sbin/snmpd -f -Lo &
# logger
tail -f /var/log/mylog.log
```

Now I want to simply call `cleanup.py` whenever a `SIGTERM` is received. I saw a few examples but my knowledge about the bash syntax is too little to actually understand and transfer onto my situation. I understand that I need a SIGTERM trap, but how do I actually call the cleanup script a wait until it's finished?

Thanks in advance!
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this method](https://raymii.org/s/snippets/Bash_Bits_Trap_Control_C_SIGTERM.html)?

If it works, you can just change what's inside the function to call your cleanup script.

Comment: Sorry I already closed the question, but it works only when I'm stoping the script with Ctrl+C. When stop the container from outside, it doesn't call the handler. Do you have any idea why?